# How do you solve this system of equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

How do you solve this system of equations ($c$ and $v$ are constants):

$\beta\left(\beta+v\gamma\right)=1$

$c^2\gamma(\beta+v\gamma)=-v$

I somehow seem to be stuck and just can't figure out how to solve them in an effective way.

Comment: If $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are your unknowns, then your system ain't linear.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Oh yeah, I inadvertently put "linear" in the title. I fixed it.

Comment: Have you tried solving the first equation for $\gamma$ and then substituting into the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

From the first equation you have
$$
\gamma=\frac{1-\beta^2}{v\beta}
$$

so the second equation becomes:
$$
c^2(1-\beta^2)=-v^2\beta^2
$$

Comment: For $\nu=0$ we have $\beta^2=1$ and $c\gamma=0$. Of course $\beta$ can't be zero.